# Woocommerece. Single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my single product page beneath product image I have reviews tab, but there is no description tab.

I need there will be two tabs description and reviews tab.

Comment: Seek help at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `product description` not `short description` in terms to see **Description** tab besides **Review**.

I have not added **description** and published my **product**. Then on my front end, it will give result as follow:

[image]

Now I am adding **Product Description** and updating it :

[image]

So after updating it, now you will able to see **description tab**:

[image]

Comment: If yes in which file you have applied classes. In tab.php?

Comment: I have not designed anything.Its wordpress default theme called `Twenty Twelve`.If you find my answer useful and well structured, you can give upvote also ;)

Comment: i have tired to give you upvote. but it give an alert of 15 reputation required to upvote. I am new to stack over flow sorry.

Comment: Do twenty twelve is compatible with woocomerece?

Comment: Thanks :) Yes! WooCommerce is compatible with twenty twelve theme.